# Package Restore Failed / .Net Core Install Bug

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget

After installing Vs 2015 Community & DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.1.exe (.Net Core), I tried to create a new .Net Core app & keep getting the 'Package Restore Failed' message.

I was about to reinstall the Win 10 since reinstalling Visual studio didn't help but saw this happens on both of my computers.

Anyone know how to fix this, please?

[image]

Comment: Can you try using the command line to run `dotnet restore` inside the project directory? What happens then?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by

1. Tools -> Options -> NugetPackageManager -> Package Sources
2. Add a new package source by clicking on the + icon
3. Set name as "dotnet-core" and source https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json
4. Open the Package Manager Console and run the command "dotnet restore"

That should fix it. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks good man, this worked for me I have some hours dealing with this

Comment: @DavideGalifi What if https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json this is having invalid certificate?

Answer (score 8):

I have the same issue in previous version of Visual Studio 2015 but it works fine in both of my Visual Studio Community 2015 and Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 with Update 3 (include KB3165756). So make sure your Visual Studio Community 2015 has installed the latest Update.

And according to the error message, one of the dependency System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles 4.0.0 does not support .NETCoreApp version 1.0. I suggest you check the project.json file in your .NET Core app, where stored all packages that installed for the default .NET Core app. Following are all my packages that installed in my default .NET Core app, please make sure all these package versions are the same with them in your app. You could copy them to your project.json file, after saving the file, these packages will be installed automatically.

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up reinstalling windows. Works now.

Comment: @weiwei. packages restored.i ended up reinstalling visual studio 2015 update 3. .net core 1.0.clear solution.thanks.saved my time.

Answer (score 3):

I solve the same problem in my project by

1. Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console
2. Select required project to restore packages from 'Default Project' list
3. Run the command "dotnet restore" on Package Manager Console
4. Rebuild the project again.

Answer (score 1):

Experienced this on Windows 8. Odd as I started getting timeouts when trying to download from NuGet for no apparent reason.

This post contained the fix for me. 
https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/1034

Create a NuGet.Config at the root of your project and add this to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <!--To inherit the global NuGet package sources remove the <clear/> line -->
    <clear />
    <add key="dotnet-core" value="https://www.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json"/>
    <add key="api.nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on the project and select `Restore Packages` in the context menu.This should fix the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a package Telerik.UI.for.asp.core: : "2016.3.1118" that was causing a lot of the packages to look as if they failed loading. Removing it solved my dependency issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because I named my solution: "Console". That apparently caused a collision with one of the default packages. If you're seeing this error, try renaming your project/solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. In my case it was showing that different version of same nugget package were there in my system. Hence I manually edited the csproj and updated the versions of the nugget so that the whole solution to points to same version.