# Package Restore Failed When Start a New Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I updated my Visual Studio 2015 to update 3 and I installed .Net core then I installed "tool preview". When I start a new project, I have a problem. The message error is "package restore failed" and there are errors in References "(Errors-see your error list)".

This is a image error when I start a new project.[image: Image erorr]

Comment: consider vs2017?

Comment: vs2015 Entreprise

Comment: i mean why not install vs2017

Comment: I buy book, and this book using vs2015 @LeiYang

Comment: Check out this link: [Package Restore Failed / .Net Core Install Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38951147/6741868), basically you have to check your 'Packages.config' if you can find it, and make sure all the versions are correct. Alternatively you could try removing those references, then readding them.

Comment: i try but dont work @KeyurPATEL

Comment: Use command prompt and try `dotnet restore` and see what happens.

Comment: @Sanket this the erorr "error MSB1003 : specify a project or solution file. the currtent working operable program or batch file"

Comment: Navigate to your project location(i.e. where project.json exist) and then try `dotnet restore`

Comment: Could you show us the output log?